# Convert factor to datetime in R

Tags: r, datetime, timestamp

I have a colum that is of factor datatype, however the timestamp is in this format:

> %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S

```
 $ fg_stop_time      : Factor w/ 8 levels "2022-05-16T20:38:19",..: 4 8
```

I cant seem to get the as.character to work it keeps coming up as NA

```
df$new_time <-strptime(x = as.character(df1$fg_stop_time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I think  it has to do with the fact that there is the T character in-between. How do I get it to recognize the 'T'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this with `lubridate` ?

```
x <- as.factor("2022-05-16T20:38:19")

library(lubridate)

y <- ymd_hms(x)

str(y)
```

`POSIXct[1:1], format: "2022-05-16 20:38:19"`

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `T` within the `format` in `strptime` or `as.POSIXct` (it may be better to use `as.POSIXct` as `strptime` returns a `list` with POSIXlt class

```
as.POSIXct("2022-05-16T20:38:19", format = "%FT%T")
```